# How To Change The Friction On A Box Collider 2D

Tags: collider

I am trying to change the friction on my box collider 2d but the option in the inspector is grey so I can't change it from there so I made this code:

```
private BoxCollider2D bc;
bc = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
bc.friction = 0;
```

When I open it in Unity I get this error:
Error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Collider2D.friction' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
Does anybody know how I can circumvent this?
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/797691/how-to-change-material-friction-from-code-for-a-ci.html) and [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/949087/changing-friction-from-code-not-working-2d.html) has a workaround for your question.

But you could just add a RigidBody 2D on your gameobject, then create a Physics Material 2D for it, which you can easily edit without writing any code at all.

Be sure the components have 2D at the end of their name or else you'll be adding 3D versions :D

Comment: Thank you, I made the material and set the friction and now my player no longer sticks to walls :P